# What is wrong with my solution for calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {3n\choose n}\left({2\over27}\right)^{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

> **problem** calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {3n\choose n}\left({2\over27}\right)^{n}$

*firstly, I KNOW that this problem is duplicated. but I want to know what is wrong with my attempt.

**my attempt**

$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{3n\choose n}{z^{2n+1}\over 2n+1}$$
satisfies $$x^3-x+z=0$$ within the convergence radius $|z|\leq{2\over3\sqrt{3}}$ by [Lagrange Inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Thus $${dx\over dz}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {3n\choose n}z^{2n}={1\over 1-3x^2}$$ and for $z={\sqrt2\over3\sqrt3}$, $x={\sqrt2\over\sqrt3}$ satisfies equation $x^3-x+z=0$.

i.e. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {3n\choose n}\left({2\over27}\right)^{n}={1\over 1-3x^2}=-1(???)$$

Comment: Your attempt doesn't make any sense. Where does the $x$ come from?

Comment: @Math1000 $x(z)$ is inverse function for $z(x)=x-x^3$

Comment: @hskimse How do you know it is wrong??

Comment: There are three possible values of $x$ given $z.$ The other two are $\frac{\pm\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Oh! I see. I think the answer is like Thomas said. The function $x(z)$ is not  invertible in the convergence disk (only locally).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ahh, I missed that. thank you! now I can sleep..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to turn @ThomasAndrews's observation into an answer, for the given value of $z$, $x$ may be equal to [any of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3-x%3D-sqrt%282%2F27%29) $\sqrt{\frac23},\,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.To avoid a paradox we need $|x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so we take the third root. In other words, the sum is$$\frac{1}{1-3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2}\approx1.366.$$

Comment: To avoid a paradox is not a good justification though.

Comment: @HudsonLima Sure it is. We know one of those $x$ is correct; we know the sum has to be positive; therefore, we know anything that follows from those two facts.

Comment: The exact value is $\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2}.$

Comment: @J.G. If you assume one must be correct ...

Comment: @HudsonLima It's not an assumption. The sum converges by the radius of convergence, so it must be $\frac{1}{1-3x^2}$ for one of the $x$ above.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for working that out. I double-checked it, but it's a relief it turns out that simple.

Comment: @J.G. Now I had time to  understand. I do agree with you. The function $x(z)$ given by the power series magically satisfy $x(z)^3-x(z)+z=0$. So $\frac{dx}{dz}(z)$ equals $\frac{1}{1-3x(z)^2}$. Then to solve the problem we need to find $x(\sqrt{\frac{2}{27}})$, which must be one of the roots.